# Displaying list of item on Pivot page & load them as pictures

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Edit :

I manage to view the list by doing the following

```
private void LoadFromLocalStorage()
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                string[] fileNames = store.GetFileNames();

                foreach (string s in fileNames)
                {

                    listBox1.Items.Add(s);

                }
            }
        }
```

How do i display it on a Pivot page as an item so when i select , i would be able to load the image.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i dont know what is the imageFolder??
```

`imageFolder` is a folder where your image is locate in your project. to execute above method just try
`LoadFromLocalStorage(YourInageFolderName)`.Its not necessary that is `imageFolder`.

Comment: HMm but i didnt give it a folder name , its ok i will give it a name then, IS folder = Directory?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to ask?Edit your comment plz.

Comment: Hmm May i know how can i add it as a pivotitem's content eg Desgin 1, Design 2 , design 3 in the Pivot item instead of a listbox. Thanks >.<

PS. I think its called TextBlock

Comment: You must store your out-put in session and retrieve the session in `Pivot page`.